Dataform Assertion message in Logs Explorer
I have a question about dataform assertion. I know it checks data and if it fails, I see an error in LogsExplorer.
My question is: Can I handle somehow the log entry in case of the error? Let's say I call tbl Source into Dataform from BigQuery. I make several computations with this output:
WITH tbl_isAnomaly AS (
SELECT *,
IF(Observed > Predicted,1,0) AS IsAnomaly
FROM tbl_Source
),

tbl_compose_msg AS (
SELECT
FORMAT("Anomaly found. Country:%t|date:%t|Observed:%t",Country,PERIOD_START,Observed) 
   AS message_text
FROM tbl_isAnomaly
WHERE IsAnomaly = 1
),

tbl_wrap_up_msg AS (
SELECT
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(message_text), '\n') as message_text
FROM tbl_compose_msg
)

SELECT message_text FROM tbl_wrap_up_msg

If nothing happens, message_text is empty (NULL). Otherwise, there is anomaly, assertion fails and error status occurs in Logs Explorer. In this anomaly case, I would like to send the message_text into log. I would use any additional info about the anomaly in email notification (through Alerting Policy in GCP).
I tried to create assertion with help of ChatGPT but it does not work. It shows this error:
"ASSERT expression should return type BOOL, but returns STRUCT<BOOL, STRING> at [3:7]."

config {
    type: "assertion",
    name: "alert_message_text_null",
}

-- Define the assertion
ASSERT(
    -- Check if all values in the message_text column are NULL
    (
        SELECT
            COUNTIF(message_text IS NOT NULL) = 0
        FROM
            ${ref("tbl_wrap_up_msg")}
    ),
    -- Custom error message if the assertion fails
    (
        SELECT
            message_text
        FROM
            ${ref("tbl_wrap_up_msg")}
        WHERE
            message_text IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT 1
    )
)

Do you have any idea about this issue? Is there any possibility to solve this within the dataform tool?
